# How to use LINQ methods like Max(), First(), and OrderBy() in LINQPad?

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

I'm trying to do a C# statement in LINQPad like this:

```
var result = 
    from tv in TankValues 
    join t in Tanks on tv.TankID equals t.ID
    orderby t.Description, tv.LogDate descending  
    select new {
        Description = t.Description,
        LogDate = tv.Max(l => l.LogDate),
        Level = tv.LevelPercentTotal
    };

result.Dump();
```

But I keep getting an error:

```
'LINQPad.User.TankValues' does not contain a definition for 'Max' and no 
extension method 'Max' accepting a first argument of type 
'LINQPad.User.TankValues' could be found (press F4 to add a using 
directive or assembly reference)
```

I pressed F4 and added every reference with "LINQ" in the name, and still no luck.

Comment: I'm afraid the message is correct. You can't call `Max` method on entity. There is always only one `LogDate` for one `TankValue`, isn't it? You probably need `group by` clause.

Comment: Ah.. so it's related to the query statement, not LinqPad limitations.

Comment: I'm afraid that's the case.

Comment: What were you trying to do with `Max`? Did you not just want to assign `tv` to `LogDate`?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek hit it on the head. I'm trying to get the most recent TankValue record for each tank. The Group By is required to do what I want.

Comment: I added the group `group tv by tv.TankID into g`, followed by the join `join t in Tanks on g.Key equals t.ID` but now I cannot figure out how to get the `Level` from the same record that the Max `LogDate` is from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to get the most recent TankValue record for each tank.

```
var result = 
    from t in Tanks
    join tv in TankValues on t.ID equals tv.TankID
    group tv by new { t.ID, t.Description } into g
    orderby g.Key.Description descending  
    select new {
        Description = g.Key.Description,
        LogDate = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.LogDate).FirstOrDefault(),
        Level = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.LogDate).FirstOrDefault().LevelPercentTotal
    };
```

Comment: That worked except for `t.Key.Description` should be `g.Key.Description`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use them on some `IQueryable` objects which basically have bunch of entities, you can not directly apply them on the entity itself.

```
var result = 
    (from tv in TankValues 
    join t in Tanks on tv.TankID equals t.ID
    orderby t.Description, tv.LogDate descending  
    select new {
        Description = t.Description,
        LogDate = tv.MaxDate,// or TankValues.Max(x=>x.LogDate) // if you need max date here
        Level = tv.LevelPercentTotal
    }).Max(l => l.LogDate)//This is just to show that Max works here;

result.Dump();
```